# opening doc from a rest service into excel/ppt online?

Tags: office-js

I have not seen any api support for excel and power point as far as getting the document and opening in word online is concerned. Can you please tell how to go about opening the document from a rest service into excel/powerpoint online?

Comment: Can you please clarify the scenario of the direction of which document you want to open from where?
At this point in time, you can access Excel Documents via the Microsoft Graph through REST - you can find information here http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs.

Comment: Basically i am able to write this code for Word, however, i dont see a similar code in Excel or powerpoint ...i dont find a context.document in powerpoint or Excel...Am i missing anything?                                                                                          Trying to view the document in excel and powerpoint from a rest call. I don’t know if there’s a way or api to do that.                                                                         Word.run(function(context){
var thisdocument = context.document;
var body = thisdocument.body;
thisdocument.body.clear();

Comment: So for Excel it is Context.Workbook. please refer to the API documentation here - http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office